# VBA: SaveCopyAs Method Outputting Cannot Find File Error

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I'm modifying a Gantt chart excel template I found online by Vertex42 for added functionality.

One of these modifications is a checkbox inside a sheet called "Config" that, when ticked, creates a backup of the Gantt chart whenever the document is opened.

For some reason, I cannot get this simple task to work.

I've tried using both the Form control and ActiveX control check boxes, with different error messages. As far as I can tell, the Form controls are unrecommended, so I'm using the code below in the ThisWorkbook excel object, based on what I've seen online.

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
    Dim backupFilename As String
    Dim formattedDateTime As String

    If Sheets("Config").OLEObjects("AutoBackupCheckbox").Object.Value = True Then
        formattedDateTime = Format(Now, "d-MMMM-yyyy, h:mm:ss")
        backupfilename = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", " - backup " & DateTime & ".xlsm")
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (backupfilename)
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is getting me the error message whenever I open the document or run the debugger,

```
Run-time error '1004':

Sorry, we couldn't find the <filename> - backup <day>-<month>-<year>, <hour>:<minute>:<seconds>.xlsm. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: After running the debugger, it's complaining on the `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` line.

UPDATE 2: Changed format of 'backupFilename' to remove the '.xlsm' in the middle.

UPDATE 3: Replaced Date with date/time without slashes, and replaced SaveAs with SaveCopyAs. Updated error message.

Comment: Add a `Debug.Print backupfilename` instead of saving for the time being. Is the result a valid filename? I think you'll have to `Format` the `Date`. That said, I assume the current error has to do with the check box.

Comment: @BigBen After running the debugger, VBA is complaining about the 'SaveAs' line. I've done as you've said and the filename is almost correct. It has an unnecessary '.xlsm' in it, which I've fixed (see updated post).

Comment: Does the `Date` have slashes in it?

Comment: @BigBen Good spot! Only problem is now I've got another error. See UPDATE 3.

Comment: Why are you using `DateTime`? I see you have `formattedDateTime`. You can't have a colon `:` in the filename either. Get `backupfilename` to something that you're *sure* you can use, by manually trying to save a copy of that file with the new file name.

Comment: @BigBen I can't believe I forgot that. Now I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument for the SaveCopyAs call is missing the path of the file.

Replace code with

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
    Dim backupFilename As String
    Dim formattedDate As String
    Dim tempFilename As String
    Dim workingPath As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    If Sheets("Config").OLEObjects("AutoBackupCheckbox").Object.Value = True Then
        formattedDate = Format(Date, "d-MMMM-yyyy, ver " & i)
        workingPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        backupFilename = Replace(workingPath, ".xlsm", " - backup " & formattedDate & ".xlsm")
        tempFilename = Dir(backupFilename)

        While tempFilename <> "" ' if file already exists
            i = i + 1
            formattedDate = Format(Date, "d-MMMM-yyyy, ver " & i)
            backupFilename = Replace(workingPath, ".xlsm", " - backup " & formattedDate & ".xlsm")
            tempFilename = Dir(backupFilename)
        Wend

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (backupFilename)
    End If
End Sub
```